# Jedis JedisPool refers to missing type error

Tags: redis, jedis

Here I'm trying to create new JedisPool, but i get the following error.

```
The constructor JedisPool(GenericObjectPool$Config, String, int, int) refers to the missing type GenericObjectPool$Config
```

This the program:

```
package redis_openfire;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig;



public class pubs {

    public static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "commonChannel";
//  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(pubs.class);
    private static Jedis publisherJedis;



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();

        final JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, "localhost", 6379, 0);

        publisherJedis = jedisPool.getResource();

        publisherJedis.publish(CHANNEL_NAME, "this is...");


    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add commons-pool to your classpath since JedisPool is commons-pool backed implementation